# MethodError: no method matching -(::Int64, ::Array{Int64,1})

Tags: arrays, julia, differential-equations

I tried playing around with [this](https://diffeq.sciml.ai/stable/features/callback_functions/index.html#Example-3:-Growing-Cell-Population-1) example in the Julia documentation. My attempt was to make the cell split into two parts that have half of the amount of protein each.

```
using OrdinaryDiffEq
const α = 0.3
function f(du,u,p,t)
  for i in 1:length(u)
    du[i] = α*u[i]/length(u)
  end
end
function condition(u,t,integrator) # Event when event_f(u,t) == 0
  1-maximum(u)
end
function affect!(integrator)
  u = integrator.u
  idxs = findall(x->x>=1-eps(eltype(u)),u)
  resize!(integrator,length(u)+length(idxs))
  u[idxs] ./ 2
  u[end-idxs:end] = 0.5
  nothing
end
callback = ContinuousCallback(condition,affect!)
u0 = [0.2]
tspan = (0.0,10.0)
prob = ODEProblem(f,u0,tspan)
sol = solve(prob,Tsit5(),callback=callback)
```

I get the error: `MethodError: no method matching -(::Int64, ::Array{Int64,1})`. I know there is a problem with `idxs = findall(x->x>=1-eps(eltype(u)),u)`, and my attempt was to put a dot between the 1 and eps, but that didn't fix it. I am using Julia 1.1.1.

Answer (score 6):

Running your code the stacktrace points to the line

```
u[end-idxs:end] = 0.5
```

The issue here is that `findall` returns an array even when it only finds one element, e.g.

```
julia> findall(x -> x > 2, [1,2,3])
1-element Array{Int64,1}:
 3
```

and you can't subtract an array from `end` in your indexing expression.

I don't understand enough about your code to figure out what `idxs` should be, but if you expect this to only return one element you could either use `first(idxs)` (or even `only(idxs)` in Julia 1.4), or replace `findall` with `findfirst`, which returns the index as an Integer (rather than an array).

Comment: I still get a MethodError, namely: "no method matching setindex_shape_check(::Float64, ::Int64)". idxs splits any cells that are greater than or equal to 1.

Comment: There might well be other errors in your code - you might want to open separate questions for those though. Overall I'm not sure I understand your goal here: I see why you want to divide all elements of `u` at positions `idxs`, but what is `end-idxs` supposed to mean? Surely you can only start indexing from a single position? Do you maybe mean `end-length(idxs)` here?